# Tree construction from csv file

Tags: python, csv, tree

I have a csv file, and want to construct a tree by reading the file contents

```
id  | screen_name |    reply_status_id |    tweet
1   |      a      |        null        |     dahgfsjhg
2   |      b      |         1          |     fcjgvujhgjhk
3   |      c      |         2          |     ououoijoskjfpokpo
4   |      d      |         1          |     giuyhewikuhieuhi
5   |      e      |         3          |     hkjhkjlkjljlkjlj
```

I want to create a tree structure based on `id` and `reply_status_id` with `tweet`.

Like,

```
      a [root]
     / \
    b   d  [childs]
   /
  c
 /
e
```

My code so far:

```
with open(file_path) as inp:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(inp)
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row[2] =='null':
            if visited == '0':
                root = Node(row[3])
                id_root = row[0]
                #inp.seek(0)
                visited = '1'
        if row[2] ==id_root:
            child = Node(row[3],root)
            child_id = row[0]
```

if `reply_staus_id == null` then keep `screen_name` as root. then in next line if reply to status id = any id then keep it as child of that id. by repeating process construct the complete tree for the file.

Comment: What error/problem do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create graph with [anytree](https://pypi.org/project/anytree/) lib:

```
import csv
from anytree import Node
from anytree.exporter import DotExporter

def find_subnodes(root_node, root_node_id, nodes):
    for row in lst:
        node_id = row[0]
        # name = regex.sub('', row[3])
        name = row[3].replace('\\"', '\'').replace('"', '')
        parent_node_id = row[2]
        if root_node_id == parent_node_id:
            node = Node(name, root_node)
            nodes[node_id] = node
            nodes = find_subnodes(node, node_id, nodes)
    return nodes

with open('rumour1.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    lst = list(reader)
r_node = Node(lst[0][3].replace('\\"', '\'').replace('"', ''))
n = {lst[0][0]: r_node}
n = find_subnodes(r_node, lst[0][0], n)
DotExporter(r_node).to_picture('tree.png')  # graphviz required
```

Based on that [CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z8paHBJVv6FJWeskYyR_6AhB2Ifor4Mz/view) you'll get:

[image]

Comment: when i run the code i got some key error in line                                                       node = Node(name, nodes[parent_id])

Comment: What value will be there in nodes[parent_id] ?

Comment: Can you share your CSV file?

Comment: Thanks... But when i'm considering tweet instead of screen_name "DotExporter(r_node).to_picture("tree.png")" shows an "CalledProcessError:". I instead uses "for pre, fill, node in RenderTree(r_node):
    print("%s%s" % (pre, node.name))" its look like: "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E_l12UfiNj3IV9fZmM2wvwtkUwCCMR_X". how to change this into tree structure?

Comment: Error: [
  File "/home/xyz/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 341, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)

CalledProcessError: Command '['dot', '/tmp/tmplzmnmqb8', '-T', 'png', '-o', 'tree.png']' returned non-zero exit status 1.]

Comment: I don't have access to that [link]("drive.google.com/open?id=1E_l12UfiNj3IV9fZmM2wvwtkUwCCMR_X) Can you share it?

Comment: Installed grapviz. [link]  https://drive.google.com/open?id=15JHvxorshTgqfPVbGU6BPqPxd9UdscUHmid-2iOSYkY

Comment: This works well for me. Exactly matches requirement.

Comment: Is it possible to add  value in edge by using anytree and graphviz? I am looking for represent the stance (+/-)last column of csv as corresponding sentences edge value.

Comment: Can you please help me to add edges in tree?

Comment: [link] https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tdN_40YeNRus7RsVDpUGbdkWjCwiT7oSanFd6MELeU4 edge label should be corresponding last column.

Comment: Please post a new question. It's a bit different task.

Answer (score -3):

You can use recursion with a simple class:

```
import csv
_, *data = csv.reader(open('filename.csv'))
new_data = [[a, b, c if not c.isdigit() else int(c), *d] for a, b, c, *d in data]
class Tree:
  def __init__(self, _d, _start='null'):
     self.head, _next = [i for i in _d if i[2] == _start], 1 if _start == 'null' else _start+1
     self.children = (lambda x:None if not x else Tree(_d, _next))([i for i in _d if i[2] == _next])
```

Now, `Tree` creates a structure that stores tweets by the "level" specified by the `reply_status_id`:

```
d = Tree(new_data)
print(d.head)
print(d.children.head)
print(d.children.children.head)
print(d.children.children.children.head)
```

Output:

```
[['1', 'a', 'null', 'dahgfsjhg']]
[['2', 'b', 1, 'fcjgvujhgjhk'], ['4', 'd', 1, 'giuyhewikuhieuhi']]
[['3', 'c', 2, 'ououoijoskjfpokpo']]
[['5', 'e', 3, 'hkjhkjlkjljlkjlj']]
```